# Seems to be an extra output in nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

This code:

```
   for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
          System.out.print(" i ");
   for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
          System.out.print(" j ");
         System.out.println();
```

Gives the following output:

```
 i  i  i  i  i  j  j  j  j  j  j
```

I cannot understand why it gives 6 `j`s instead of 5. Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Comment: try to think when the test fails on first for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` applies the increment every time the loop finishes. The condition is checked before beginning the next loop, so `i` will be 6 instead of 5 by the time your second loop starts.

Fix this by making the second condition `j<i` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop's invariant is

```
i <= 5
```

therefore the loop will continue to iterate until that invariant no longer holds. So when you reach the second loop, you can be sure that `i` is *not* less than or equal 5; in other words, it is *greater than* 5.

Answer (score 2):

`i` will be 6 when the `j` `for-loop` enters since the first loop would terminate at `i==6` and not `i==5` as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop stops when i failed the condition `i <= 5`, which means `i=6`.

So the second loop is exactly as

```
 for (j = 1; j <= 6; j++) System.out.print(" j ");
```

Which print 6 j.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the "i for", i equals 6, that's why j is printed 6 times.

Answer (score 2):

The value of i is 6 when it finished the 1st loop. Read more about post increment operator and for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use debug then you will realize this by your won. The moment first for loop exit `i=6` and then your second will runs loop runs 6 times since upper limit for `j` is now `6`. Then you get `6 js`